# Running Compact Framework 1.0 Application On Windows Mobile 6.1 And Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile

I have a application developed based on Compact Framework 1.0. I can run it, on Operating Systems that version number is smaller than Windows Mobile 6.1

But I can't use it on Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5.

Before installing app, I install these cabs:

1 - netcf.all.wce4.ARMV4I
2 - sqlce20.ppc.wce5.armv4i
3 - sqlce20.dev.ppc.wce5.armv4i

Do anyone has an idea about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe device already has CF 2.0 (or 3.5) in ROM and my guess is that trying to install the older runtimes on top of that is causing issues for the GAC.  The good news is that you don't need to install the older runtimes, you can just [update your application's config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5cd9b2c(VS.80).aspx) to allow the newer runtimes to load the application.

This way you can have the application load and run with the already-installed runtimes as-is, or even tell the runtimes to use compatibility mode.